# Suddenly I am not able to build for the iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, ios-simulator

Sometimes one wants to really hate the Apple development environment.  Seriously, does it need to be this complicated?

My problem is this.  I am no longer able to build my project to the Simulator.  I am getting the following errors.  I realize it is a linker error - what I dont understand is 1) why this suddenly is no longer working, and 2) how come it will not pick the right SDK (which is the reason for the linker error).

Apple Magik is crazy frustrating.

Also, I just recently upgraded to Snow Leopard and XCode 3.2 although it was working after the upgrade.

Thanks!
Bryan

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChunderCats.app/ChunderCats normal i386
cd /Users/bryan/projects/iPhone/ChunderCats
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.1.sdk -L/Users/bryan/projects/iPhone/ChunderCats/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib -F/Users/bryan/projects/iPhone/ChunderCats/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/bryan/projects/iPhone/ChunderCats/build/ChunderCats.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChunderCats.build/Objects-normal/i386/ChunderCats.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lsqlite3 -o /Users/bryan/projects/iPhone/ChunderCats/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChunderCats.app/ChunderCats

ld: warning: in /Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: warning: in /Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: warning: in /Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: warning: in /Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: warning: in /Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: warning: in /Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols:
  ".objc_class_name_UIApplication", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIApplication in MenuViewController.o
  ".objc_class_name_NSNotificationCenter", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNotificationCenter in MenuViewController.o
  ".objc_class_name_NSObject", referenced from:
      .objc_class_name_ChunderCatsAppDelegate in ChunderCatsAppDelegate.o
  "_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut", referenced from:
      _kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut$non_lazy_ptr in MenuViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_free", referenced from:
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
  "_NSLog", referenced from:
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillResignActive:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationDidBecomeActive:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController checkDevice] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController newGameButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController resumeGameButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController optionsButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController howToPlayButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController soundSwitch:] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController vibrateSwitch:] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController bubbleThoughtsSwitch:] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController backstorySwitch:] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController prevButton:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController nextButton:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
  "_objc_setProperty", referenced from:
      -[ChunderCatsAppDelegate setWindow:] in ChunderCatsAppDelegate.o
      -[MenuViewController setHowToPlayButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController setOptionsButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController setResumeGameButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController setNewGameButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController setHowToPlayViewController:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController setOptionsViewController:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController setBasedOnATrueStoryImageView:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController setSplashImageView:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController setLogoImageView:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController setBackgroundImageView:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController setBackButton:] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController setBackstorySwitch:] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController setBubbleThoughtsSwitch:] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController setVibrateLabel:] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController setVibrateSwitch:] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController setSoundSwitch:] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setHowToPlayImageView:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setBackButton:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setNextButton:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setPrevButton:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setNextButtonView:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setPrevButtonView:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setHowToPlayImage7:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setHowToPlayImage6:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setHowToPlayImage5:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setHowToPlayImage4:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setHowToPlayImage3:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setHowToPlayImage2:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController setHowToPlayImage1:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
  "_exit", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.5.o
  ".objc_class_name_CAMediaTimingFunction", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CAMediaTimingFunction in MenuViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
  ".objc_class_name_NSBundle", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSBundle in MenuViewController.o
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSBundle in HowToPlayViewController.o
  ".objc_class_name_UIColor", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIColor in MenuViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
  "_UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification", referenced from:
      _UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification$non_lazy_ptr in MenuViewController.o
  ".objc_class_name_NSString", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in MenuViewController.o
  "_objc_msgSendSuper", referenced from:
      -[ChunderCatsAppDelegate dealloc] in ChunderCatsAppDelegate.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dealloc] in MenuViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController viewDidLoad] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController dealloc] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController viewDidLoad] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[HowToPlayViewController dealloc] in HowToPlayViewController.o
      -[IntroViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in IntroViewController.o
      -[IntroViewController dealloc] in IntroViewController.o
  ".objc_class_name_UIImage", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIImage in MenuViewController.o
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIImage in HowToPlayViewController.o
  ".objc_class_name_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSAutoreleasePool in main.o
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
  ".objc_class_name_NSTimer", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSTimer in MenuViewController.o
  "_UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification", referenced from:
      _UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification$non_lazy_ptr in MenuViewController.o
  "_NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains", referenced from:
      -[MenuViewController dataFilePath] in MenuViewController.o
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      cfstring=MenuViewController in ChunderCatsAppDelegate.o
      cfstring=Init
 in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=Failed to open database in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=opened database: %@ in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FIELDS (ROW INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, FIELD_DATA REAL); in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=Error creating table: %s in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=executed: %@ in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=SELECT ROW, FIELD_DATA FROM FIELDS ORDER BY ROW in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=row=%d, value=%f in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=png in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=background-composite-left in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=based-on-a-true-story in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=splash in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=intro-screen in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=opacity in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=name in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=frame0Animation in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=fadeOutAnimation in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=frame1Animation in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=fadeAnimation in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=animation stopped: %@ in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=frame2Animation in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=[MainViewController] Received memory warning... in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=application will resign active in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=[MainViewController] applicationDidBecomeActive in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=application will terminate in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=YES in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=NO in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=Saving: soundOption=%@ in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=INSERT OR REPLACE INTO FIELDS (ROW, FIELD_DATA) VALUES (%d, %f); in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=Error updating tables: %s in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=Saving: vibrateOption=%@ in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=Saving: bubbleThoughts=%@ in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=This device is: %@ in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=iPhone in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=data.sqlite3 in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=new game in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=resume game in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=options in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=OptionsViewController in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=how to play in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=HowToPlayViewController in MenuViewController.o
      cfstring=YES in OptionsViewController.o
      cfstring=NO in OptionsViewController.o
      cfstring=toggleSwitch = %@ in OptionsViewController.o
      cfstring=vibrateSwitch = %@ in OptionsViewController.o
      cfstring=bubbleThoughtsSwitch = %@ in OptionsViewController.o
      cfstring=backstorySwitch = %@ in OptionsViewController.o
      cfstring=png in HowToPlayViewController.o
      cfstring=how-to-play-01 in HowToPlayViewController.o
      cfstring=how-to-play-02 in HowToPlayViewController.o
      cfstring=how-to-play-03 in HowToPlayViewController.o
      cfstring=how-to-play-04 in HowToPlayViewController.o
      cfstring=how-to-play-05 in HowToPlayViewController.o
      cfstring=how-to-play-06 in HowToPlayViewController.o
      cfstring=how-to-play-07 in HowToPlayViewController.o
      cfstring=prev in HowToPlayViewController.o
      cfstring=next in HowToPlayViewController.o
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
      _main in main.o
      -[ChunderCatsAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in ChunderCatsAppDelegate.o
      -[ChunderCatsAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in ChunderCatsAppDelegate.o
      -[ChunderCatsAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in ChunderCatsAppDelegate.o
      -[ChunderCatsAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in ChunderCatsAppDelegate.o
      -[ChunderCatsAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in ChunderCatsAppDelegate.o
      -[ChunderCatsAppDelegate dealloc] in ChunderCatsAppDelegate.o
      -[ChunderCatsAppDelegate dealloc] in ChunderCatsAppDelegate.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidLoad] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewTimer:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController animationDidStop:finished:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidUnload] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidUnload] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidUnload] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController viewDidUnload] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dealloc] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dealloc] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dealloc] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dealloc] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dealloc] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dealloc] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dealloc] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dealloc] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dealloc] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dealloc] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController applicationWillTerminate:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController checkDevice] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController checkDevice] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController checkDevice] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dataFilePath] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController dataFilePath] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController optionsButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController optionsButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController optionsButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController optionsButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController optionsButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController howToPlayButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController howToPlayButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController howToPlayButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController howToPlayButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[MenuViewController howToPlayButton:] in MenuViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController viewDidLoad] in OptionsViewController.o
      -[OptionsViewController viewDidLoad] in OptionsViewController.o
      ...
```

Comment: Do you that the question only includes an ld warning, and it is cutoff? Where is the end of the warning? And are there any errors?

Comment: While the output may be cut off, the important part it at the beginning:

/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file Undefined symbols: ".objc_class_name_UIApplication", referenced from: literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIApplication in MenuViewController.o

Right after the warning that it is complaining that "missing required architecture i386 in file".  This is correct because it is trying to link against the iphone libraries which are ARM where as the simulator libraries are i386 (Intel).

Comment: Holy wall of text, Batman!

Comment: the curious thing I cannot edit the post, I get a timeout :D

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this issue for myself today. See my answer here: [Build Error - missing required architecture i386 in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file/1467238#1467238)

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to link against the iPhoneOS.platform when it should be linking to the iPhoneSimulator.platform

When you expand the **Link** build result, this is what your should see:

```
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk
```

I can only suggest playing with the **Base SDK** and **iPhone Deployment Target** properties of your target's build settings and your project's build settings.

Other than that, I'd guess it's a problem with your XCode install rather than your project.

Answer (score 0):

It is very frustrating. Are you able to compile other projects to the simulator?

In one case, I ended up starting a whole new project and bringing all my assets and files in. That sounds really bad, but it was painless compared to trying to isolate whatever it was I had done to break it.

Comment: I follow your approach sometimes. However, not figuring out where the problem is, is likely going to cause you to fall into the same problem again. Better spend time figuring it out first time, unless you are under a tight deadline

Comment: True. But sometimes if you can get it working as a new project, you can compare that to the non-working project to see what the difference is.

Comment: Yes, I am able to build for the iPhone 3.1 device no problem.  This is just happening with the Simulator.   The simulator is an i386 platform while the device is an arm.  I do not know the magik of Xcode well enough...

Comment: I'm asking if you can build other projects (like examples) for the simulator (not the device).

Comment: That's not the question.  If you create a brand new project, can that compile for the simulator?  If not, then try installing the latest XCode on the iPhone development portal.  If you can compile that for the simulator, make a new project with the same name and just copy all of the files you have now into that new project.

Comment: For whatever reason, the project got corrupted - I was able to create a new project and carefully copy all the files over.  What a royal pain in the arse!!!!

Comment: Well I'm glad you finally got it working. I had similar things happen 2 or 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the new Xcode from the Apple iPhone Developer Center/page/thing?  The Xcode shipped with Snow Leopard does not come with the iPhone libraries; those are only available after downloading the awesomely sized 2+gig developer package.

Comment: Yeah, I have the most recent SDK and installed the Simulator package.  Both directories are present in the /Developer/Platforms directory.