# Errors when building iPhone app in Xcode

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode

I get this error (and 27 others) when trying to build my application. I'm not sure what has changed to cause this, but i have no clue what the error actually means? This is an example of where i am calling `appDelegate = (iTourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

```
  ".objc_class_name_UIApplication", referenced from:
  literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIApplication in MapViewController.o
```

Another example

```
  ".objc_class_name_NSString", referenced from:
  literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in ListTableViewController.o
```

I tried a clean build but no success.

Any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by searching for `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` under `/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */` in project.pbxproject (in xcodeproj bundle) and removing that entry. Back up first! Thanks to Sean Roehnelt of SO for this answer on a different post

[Build error Missing required architecture i386 in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file/1469974#1469974)