# Pesky compiler error on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Trying to get MGTwitterEngine app to build. Getting one pesky error. The following ERROR.

```
ld warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like a proper solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file).