# Linker error (only simulator) with own library after update to iPhone SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-construction, ios-simulator, ios4

I recently updated to iPhone SDK 4.0 and are no longer able to build my project for the iPhone simulator. The problem is that classes of one of my own libraries can no longer be found by ld:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Book", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref-to-Book in Category.o
   (maybe you meant: ...)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already read some other posts about similar problems, like e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528114/xcode-linker-error-on-iphone-app-only-on-simulator). "Unfortunately", my problem has nothing to do with a SDK framework, but with my own lib, so the solutions mentioned there are not applicable here.

The library is included under "Link Binary With Libraries" of my target, library search paths are correct (checked this with XCode and with a plain text editor directly in my project file) and correctly added to the gcc command.

I'm using iPhone Simulator 3.2 as Base SDK, but the same problem occurs with SDK 4.0. Again, this works with my device target but not with my simulator target. It worked with both, though, before I updated from iPhone SDK 3.2 to 4.0. I was also able to reproduce this error by creating a new project with only one file and the linked lib. However, the lib should be okay as it worked with simulator 3.2 before I updated XCode and my SDK.

More Facts: Mac OS X 10.6.3, XCode 3.2.3 64-Bit, iPhone OS 3.2, GCC 4.2

Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

After reinstalling SDK 3.2, everything worked as expected again. It must be noted, that the SDKs in folder /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs are overwritten with each installation. I then tried to reinstall SDK 4.0 again and the same error as above occurred. I didn't change anything in my project and always used 3.2 as Base SDK.

The problem can therefore possibly be narrowed down to the following options:

- Apple changed sth. in the Simulator SDK 3.2 that causes the problem
- a change in XCode 3.2.3 causes the problem
- wrong/missing compiler flags while building my own library (those flags, however, would only cause problems with a changed SDK or the changed IDE)

I also did a folder diff on /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk for both the old and the new version of this folder. It turned out that there are actually minor changes within the "same" SDK. I still think it's an IDE/compiler flag problem, though.

Anybody any ideas? I don't want to stick to 3.2 forever...

Comment: I had the same problem. Mysteriously it only occured for the "Release" but nor for the "Debug" build, eventhough I did not change anything after updating to the 4.0 SDK. However, I haven't examined this further yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out which flags were missing in my compiler call to build my lib. So, to answer my question: If anybody has problems linking his/her own static lib to a target in XCode 3.2.3 (using iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk or iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk), you need to build your lib with the following two flags:

-fobjc-abi-version=2

-fobjc-legacy-dispatch

Thanks again to [PhoneyDeveloper](http://forums.macrumors.com/member.php?u=223017) for [his hints](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=956090).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you recompile your libraries with the same base SDK as you're using for your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use the same base SDK, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. As suggested in another forum (http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=956090), I built my lib with XCode instead of the command line and it worked. Although I then used the same gcc flags with both command line and XCode, the manually built lib still won't work with my app...

Answer (score 0):

Another thought- this has happened to me in the past even when libraries **weren't** involved.

Double check that you haven't imported files using the 'group folder references' option.  It seems that this gives Xcode a headache.  (At least it did in my case.)

Answer (score 0):

i got solved this when i removed flags like (-ObjC, -all_load) under 'Other Linker Flags' which I was using in the project.there was -all_load conflict actually.