# Location Manager with iMac

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, cllocationmanager, i386

I am using CLLocationManager.

I got this compile error:

```
Ld /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BadgerNew.app/BadgerNew normal i386
    cd /Users/Teguh/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Intermediates/BadgerNew.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BadgerNew.build/Objects-normal/i386/BadgerNew.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -o /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-bjopcgcgsjkcvcevflfbvsjwfgnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BadgerNew.app/BadgerNew

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UtilitiesQuick.o
  "_kCLLocationAccuracyBest", referenced from:
      -[BNUtilitiesQuick init] in UtilitiesQuick.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So how am I supposed to program CLLocationmanager? I mean does that mean location manager is not available on iMac?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add `CoreLocation.framework` to your project.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue.. after a long struggle I found the issue..

I resolved it this way..

1. Go to Build Settings
2. Search for 'framework search path'
3. And delete the pre filled path.

Now it works perfectly..  I have given the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544985/missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file/14013763#14013763).. hope it helps some one..