# Where is _kCLLocationAccuracyBest defined?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, cllocationmanager

If I want to use it, should I add a framework or just header file?

I got this error that it's a symbol not found

Comment: possible duplicate of [Location Manager with iMac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168660/location-manager-with-imac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010237), it's declared in CLLocation.h.  You should add the CoreLocation framework.  Also, it appears to have no underscore out in front.  That could be your problem.

Comment: The underscore is because this is a symbol name as reported by the linker, not the original variable name.