# What is $(inherited) in Xcode's search path settings?

Tags: xcode

What is the `$(inherited)` search path setting?

I've modified the  header and library search path settings regarding OpenSSL for iPad and this issue along with the recursive option for given path was the main culprit.

When I rearranged my search paths to first look into directories and then into `$(inherited)`, the iPad builds were working.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I'm looking for a documentation, too. But I made the experience, that `$(inherited)` can be used to inherit build settings from the project level to the target level. When you define library or header search paths at the project level you can use `$(inherited)` in the target build settings to use these search paths in the search paths of the project targets.

Comment: I think this is actually $(inherited), not $(inherit).

Answer (score 64):

If you go to a Target's Build Settings and switch to Level view, you can see the flow of inheritance from right to left

```
Resolved <- Target <- xcconfig <- Project <- iOS Default
```

So `$(inherited)` in a Target's Build Setting means that Target inherits settings from xcconfig and Project.

Comment: Where/what is xcconfig?

Comment: This answer is awesome! Very clear of where the final value comes.

Comment: Super helpful, especially the Levels view tip. I work on a large project and we actually have custom xcconfig files imported that overrides the higher level Project settings (which I didn't know). The Levels view showed me exactly where the inherited values were coming from. For of a "teach a man how to fish" answer :)

Comment: @ricardo looking for your xcconfig file, try `find . -name '*xcconfig' -print` or `find . -name '*xcconfig' -print -exec grep OTHER_LDFLAGS {} \;`

Answer (score 9):

**Example of Overriding** build setting variables set on the Project or Target level by reassigning the value of that variable in a xcconfig file.

```
// Variable set in the project file, previous level
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC

// lib.xcconfig
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -framework Security
```

^ When compiling with this, the previous value of OTHER_LDFLAGS `-ObjC` is going to be overridden by the new value `-framework Security`.

**Example of Inheriting** build setting variables set on the Project or Target level by appending to the previous value of that variable in a xcconfig file. Think of `$(inherited)` as a special variable that can be used to get the existing value of a variable so that assignment to same variable isn't destructive.

```
// Variable set in the project file, previous level
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC

// lib.xcconfig
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -framework Security
```

^ When compiling with this, the value of OTHER_LDFLAGS is going to be `-ObjC -framework Security`.

Example found at https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html

Comment: very well explained. ty

Comment: doesn't the $(inherited) flag get set in the project file not the lib.xcconfig ?

Answer (score 5):

ADDENDUM:
with `$(inherited)` *Build Settings->Library Search Path* is automatically populated when you add a library to a target by clicking in the Target Membership right-hand pane. This does not happen otherwise.

Comment: I didn't find this to be the case, at least not as of Xcode 7.  I have $(inherited) set in both the project, and the target (tried them individually too), then added a custom framework to my specific target but it didn't get added to the search paths.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: Hard to keep up with Xcode updates... it might have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode $(inherited)**

[[Xcode ${<variable_name>} syntax]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66984167/4770877)

Xcode variable can be defined on different levels(Project, .xcconfig, Target, Default). When you use `Build Settings -> Levels` tab you can check hierarchy and **Resolved** result

`$(inherited)` uses variable value from **super level**.

Please note several things:

- It is useful when you should concatenate the result value like `$(inherited)-myPrefix`. It is not so useful to use as a standalone expression because even when you delete `$(inherited)` or any other value from successor(Target is successor of Project) Xcode automatically change this value based on predecessor
- You are able to set `.xcconfig` on Project level and Target level, that is why the result hierarchy is not constant

```
Resolved <- Target <- Target .xcconfig <- Project <- Project .xcconfig <- Default
```

For example Target = `$(inherited)`

`.xcconfig` on Project level
[image]

`.xcconfig` on Target level
[image]

[[.xcconfig]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64266553/4770877)

[[CocaPods inherit!]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56273013/4770877)