# Xcode 7.2 bug: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

I'm having an issue with Xcode 7.2 and the linker command.

Since i added the google analitycs library WITHOUT POD, in my project, everytime y close the project and reopen it, i get this error.

[image]

What i have to do to workaround this problem is remove the library reference and add it again, and all goes well.

[image]

What i want to know is if this is a bug or i'm doing something wrong. Thanks!

EDIT:

this is the location of the library

[image]

Comment: Can you specify the exact location of the Google Analytics library file location in finder?

Comment: "/Users/alfredo/Desktop/PROYECTOS IOS/Personal Musica/Personal Musica/GoogleAnalytics" i'm starting to think is because of the space in "Pesonal Musica" folder...

Comment: @Varun i edited the question with a photo of the path

Comment: Go to your build settings -> Search "library search paths" and click on that row. Let me know what data is shown. It should look something like this $SRCROOT/"Personal Musica". Also check if BITCODE is set to NO

Comment: $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Personal Musica/GoogleAnalytics $(PROJECT_DIR)/Personal Musica/GoogleAnalytics $(PROJECT_DIR)/Personal Musica/GoogleAnalytics $(PROJECT_DIR)/Personal Musica/GoogleAnalytics $(PROJECT_DIR)/Personal Musica/GoogleAnalytics $(PROJECT_DIR)/Personal Musica/GoogleAnalytics $(PROJECT_DIR)/Personal Musica/GoogleAnalytics $(PROJECT_DIR)/Personal Musica/GoogleAnalytics $(PROJECT_DIR)/Personal Musica/GoogleAnalytics BITCODE is set to NO

Comment: the repetition of the "$(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Personal Musica/GoogleAnalytics" is because i add the reference everytime the error happens, right?

Comment: Solution is simple, drag googleAnalytics folder into library search path window. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the problem. Your library search path should have been like this

`$(PROJECT_DIR)/"Personal Musica"/GoogleAnalytics`

Add double quotes wherever there are folders with 2 words. xocde tries to slpit the folder name. This will generate an error. Your linker error is saying the exact thing. It's splitting the analytics folder when it encounters folder with two words.

Comment: ok so i made this: $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/"Personal Musica"/GoogleAnalytics What is $(inherited)?

Comment: Here's a reference link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343122/what-is-inherited-in-xcodes-search-path-settings and https://amokafullofstuff.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/cocoapods-the-inherited-flag/