# Project Directory Name Change Resulting in "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing an app using Xcode 7.2.1
While trying to utilize Cocoapods, I realized I didn't know how to cd into a directory that had spaces in its name within Terminal.  Therefore, in Finder, I navigated to my directory and changed its name from "In Moment" to "InMoment".  Going back into Xcode and rebuilding the file resulted in an error message popup, that I blinded accepted (it prompted me if I wanted to re-organize/re-something).  Panicking, I went back into Finder to change the name back to "In Moment".  However, I still receive the "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" Build Fail.

I've looked at solutions for modifying my Info.plist, and for editing my Schemes, but they don't seem to affect anything.  Any help, or referencing where I could find help would be greatly appreciated.  Much thanks.

Comment: Please refer this answer. Probable duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205814/xcode-7-2-bug-library-not-found-for-lgoogleanalyticsservices/35244633#35244633

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  That reference link allowed me to build the project.  Although, to avoid this situation later, just to make sure; whenever I would like to reference a file name with white space in between words, I should put quotation marks around them?

Comment: You should use this only if libraries or frameworks are added.

Comment: please add your error. So it's easy to understand.