# Library not found for -lOAuth

Tags: ios, linker-errors

> i am trying to run an app which was build on old xcode 5. i want to run that app on new xcode but It gives clang error library not found -lOAuth.

[image]

Please help how to fix this error.
Any Help.

Comment: Install the library or give its path explicitly? but you seem to be missing more than that, given the warnings which preceede it.

Comment: This is a duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205814/xcode-7-2-bug-library-not-found-for-lgoogleanalyticsservices/35244633#35244633. Please modify your library search path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add that library to general setting of the project

[image]