# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am integrating Firebase in my app according to the instructions and added [FIRApp configure]; in the code however, while compiling the app I am getting the following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Did CocoaPods write any warnings due to pods installation? I fixed a similar issue by setting **`OTHER_LDFLAGS`** build settings to **`$(inherited)`** flag.

Comment: If you are wondering what does `$(inherited)`  even mean, check this explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343122/what-is-inherited-in-xcodes-search-path-settings

Comment: You mean I should have read those warnings instead of shrugging them off?  Whodathunk!  (Thank you... feeling sheepish)

Comment: I did that. But I am getting this error : "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: Integration is terrible, why other libs work without extra steps? I had to make two with firebase, this worked.

Comment: Be careful that all the different flavours (Debug, Release) of "Other Linker Flags" are set to $(inherited)

Comment: working for me. I am using xCode 12 beta 4.
Just add $(inherited) & -ObjC, other are removed .
fix my problem 
Thanks @supp-f

Answer (score 1):

`s.static_framework = true`

to podspec worked for me

URL: [How to use Firebase SDK as a Pod dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290640/how-to-use-firebase-sdk-as-a-pod-dependency)

Comment: Thanks! You saved me!

Answer (score 0):

Updating the pod "Architectures" to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put
$(inherited) -ObjC -framework "AVFoundation" -framework "AudioToolbox" -framework "CFNetwork" -framework "CoreGraphics" -framework "CoreMedia" -framework "CoreMotion" -framework "CoreTelephony" -framework "CoreVideo" -framework "GLKit" -framework "GoogleMobileAds" -framework "MediaPlayer" -framework "MessageUI" -framework "MobileCoreServices" -framework "OpenGLES" -framework "QuartzCore" -framework "Security" -framework "StoreKit" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -weak_framework "AdSupport" -weak_framework "JavaScriptCore" -weak_framework "SafariServices" -weak_framework "WebKit"

Comment: Hi Somplesi! Could you provide some more information about how your answer solves the problem?

Comment: It works with: -ObjC -framework "AVFound.....................ework "SafariServices" -weak_framework "WebKit" into "Other Linker Flags" field of "Build Setting" of "Targets" of your App