# Xcode release build problem Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAuth

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, fbsdk

I'm having a problem when I'm trying to build an Xcode project.

Project: The project is a solution made it in react native the package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "ENVFILE=.env.dev react-native run-android --variant=debug",
    "android-prod": "ENVFILE=.env.prod react-native run-android --variant=release",
    "android-prod-debug": "ENVFILE=.env.prod react-native run-android --variant=debug",
    "android-dev-local": "ENVFILE=.env.local.dev react-native run-android --variant=debug",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start --reset-cache",
    "metro": "DEBUG=* & react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "rn-link": "react-native link"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^1.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui": "^4.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^4.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "7.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "7.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "7.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/iid": "^7.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "7.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.7.7",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.18",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.5",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/numeral": "^0.0.27",
    "@types/ramda": "^0.27.4",
    "@types/react-native-fbsdk": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.5",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/recompose": "^0.30.7",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "i18next": "^19.4.4",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.5",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "native-base": "2.13.12",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "ramda": "^0.27.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.4.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-config": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.5.6",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
    "react-native-video": "5.0.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.8.3",
    "react-native-youtube": "^2.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.62.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.27.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

and the error that I'm having its when I make the release build in Xcode (in debug mode it's works ok).

The error that I'm having is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjCbZ.png)

Showing All Errors Only

**
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAuth
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FBSDKAppEvents
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate**

My pod file it's

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

def add_flipper_pods!(versions = {})
  versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.33.1'
  versions['DoubleConversion'] ||= '1.1.7'
  versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '~> 2.1'
  versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.3.6'
  versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] ||= '~> 0.0.4'
  versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '~> 1.0'

  pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'

  # List all transitive dependencies for FlipperKit pods
  # to avoid them being linked in Release builds
  pod 'Flipper', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-DoubleConversion', versions['DoubleConversion'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Folly', versions['Flipper-Folly'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Glog', versions['Flipper-Glog'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-PeerTalk', versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-RSocket', versions['Flipper-RSocket'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/Core', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/CppBridge', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBDefines', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
end

# Post Install processing for Flipper
def flipper_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'YogaKit'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'YourHouseWithAmalia' do
  # Pods for YourHouseWithAmalia
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'
  pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  #pod 'Permission-Reminders', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Reminders.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications.podspec"
  pod 'RNFBMessaging', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging'
  pod 'RNFBIid', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/iid'
  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'
  pod 'react-native-config', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-config'

  target 'YourHouseWithAmaliaTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  add_flipper_pods!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'YourHouseWithAmalia-tvOS' do
  # Pods for YourHouseWithAmalia-tvOS

  target 'YourHouseWithAmalia-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

and Im tried to:

- pod deintegrate and pod install again.
- delete iOS folder and create again.
  / clean project, close Xcode, etc.

Do you know what's happen and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried deleting your project folder in `Preferences` -> `Locations` -> `Derived Data`?

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried deleting all folders there, clean project, build again but I'm still having the error.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344676/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-objc-class-firapp

Comment: I'm tried to update the pod "Architectures" to $(ARCHS_STANDARD), s.static_framework = true in all specs files but I'm still having the error