# How to fix the error:ndefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp". When I try to init with [FIRApp configure]

Tags: firebase, sdk, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

dependency firebase sdk via cocoa

`pod ‘Firebase’, ‘10.5.0’`

and ten try to configure fireapp via
`[FIRApp configure]`

then I get this error:
`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I have tried very many solutions in this topic:
[Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344676/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-objc-class-firapp)

none of them works.
Any help will be appreciated.

please, fix this error