# use_framework! in Podfile caused 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' not found

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, ios-frameworks, podfile

I'm currently integrating a private library from vendor which they mentioned it's required to have `use_framework!` added in `Podfile`. Apparently I found out from them, the framework is written in Objective-C, if so.. why is `use_framework!` needed?  I thought [this is the reason why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41210375/4311268) we use `use_framework!`

> use_frameworks tells CocoaPods that you want to use Frameworks instead of Static Libraries. Since Swift does not support Static Libraries you have to use frameworks.

Currently I'm facing this build time issue `'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' not found` in `AppDelegate.h`

**Side info**,

1. My project is running on React Native Firebase v6, hence I have added `# $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true` to handle the  `use_framework!` case. [Read more about this here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3253#issuecomment-607782071).
2. I'll get the following error if I don't append `use_framework!`

> Framework not found helloFramework

3. Here's the Xcode error . . . .
   [image]
4. I confirmed my project's scheme has the React Bulleyes icon from `podfile` and I'm building on this scheme
   [image]

**My questions**, why do I get this issue when I use `use_frameworks!` ? What's is the correct way to handle this issue?

[image]

**Update:**

- Created issue at [React Native Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29872)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR

Append `$(inherited)` at Framework Search Paths .

---

### Explanation

Apparently, when we apply `use_frameworks!` at `Podfile`. Our Xcode project will replace `libPods-{projectName}.a` with `Pods_{projectName}.framework`.

Since our project is relying on Frameworks to build, we have to append `$(inherited)` to `Framework Search Paths` at Target > Build Settings > Search Paths > Framework Search Paths. This will inherit the build settings from project level to target level. [Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21548497/4311268)