# i386 Architecture Problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, device

I'm having a horrible problem. My code runs on the device but not on the simulator and gives me this error:

```
Ld /Users/fgringo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuessTheBalls-bgplgtjujgzwbnhkbratlkdnnrzm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuessTheBalls.app/GuessTheBalls normal i386
    cd "/Users/fgringo/Desktop/SecretBalls_V1.1 Working"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/fgringo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuessTheBalls-bgplgtjujgzwbnhkbratlkdnnrzm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/fgringo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuessTheBalls-bgplgtjujgzwbnhkbratlkdnnrzm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-F/Users/fgringo/Desktop/SecretBalls_V1.1 Working" -filelist /Users/fgringo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuessTheBalls-bgplgtjujgzwbnhkbratlkdnnrzm/Build/Intermediates/GuessTheBalls.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuessTheBalls.build/Objects-normal/i386/GuessTheBalls.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 /usr/lib/gcrt1.o -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AudioToolbox -framework GameKit -o /Users/fgringo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuessTheBalls-bgplgtjujgzwbnhkbratlkdnnrzm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuessTheBalls.app/GuessTheBalls

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/fgringo/Desktop/SecretBalls_V1.1 Working/GameKit.framework/GameKit, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: duplicate symbol start in /usr/lib/gcrt1.o and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.6.o for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

But get a better look at the last sentences:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/fgringo/Desktop/SecretBalls_V1.1 Working/GameKit.framework/GameKit, missing required architecture i386 in file

ld: duplicate symbol start in /usr/lib/gcrt1.o and /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.6.o for architecture i386
collect2: 

ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

I tried the iOS simulators, tried to do some other changes that I really don't remember, but that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think a  duplicate file is present. if it is not present try cleaning it and building it again.

Answer (score -3):

[Build Error - missing required architecture i386 in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file)

Good luck