# iphone how to compress audio file size

Tags: iphone

in iphone application i need to compress audio file (Example .caf sound file) after sound record.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-aac-compressed-audio-conversion-on-ios/

Comment: I am getting  "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" if I just import the two class files (.m and .h). Any help on that ?

Comment: @ahsan : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file