# How to compress a audio file in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an application in which I am recording a long audio.
I want this audio file to save in the server, using a web service. 
I want to compress the file and then upload it in the server for fast uploading.

Please suggest me how to compress a audio file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"Give AQuA Wideband a try:

http://www.sevana.fi/aqua_music.php

The procedure is simple, just request an evaluation with MP3 and OGG optimization scripts and the suite and you get the best quality/compression ratio out of your audio. I am sure if you ask for hints to make sure it fits 100Mb they will help you too."

[iphone how to compress audio file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752451/iphone-how-to-compress-audio-file-size)