# ld warning: missing required architecture i386 in file

Tags: iphone

When I compile my sqlite-based app I get the following error. What is the solution?

> ld: warning: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build Error - missing required architecture i386 in file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file)

Comment: Read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file/1467238#1467238). Dont duplicate questions.