# App runs fine on iphone but fails in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Build Error - missing required architecture i386 in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file)

I have searched high and low for an answer to this problem but just have not found a solution.

Basically I have made an app that works just fine when run from an actual iphone (3GS and 4) but it will not run in the iphone simulator.

When I try to run it through the sim it gives me two warnings and one error.

The warnings are that it is ignoring AVFoundationFramework and CoreFoundationFramework. It says that it is missing the required architecture i386 in file for architecture i386. - To me this is saying that these files are not supported for a intel cpu - is that correct?

Then the error tells me

> "Command
>   Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1"

If anyone can tell me of a fix for this that would be most appreciated, or if you could tell me that it simply won't run in the simulator - that would also be appreciated.

thankyou.

Comment: It sounds like an inconsistency in the different Targets (Device/Simulator). You could check out those settings, especially the target architectures.

Comment: can you post complete error message getting by clicking on more link at error message.

Comment: Thankyou guys for the suggestions / messages. I kept researching just after posting this question and have found the answer which has fixed it. I'll answer it now.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer my own question (as I am a new user) so I will post here: I managed to find the answer on stackoverflow which (I was afraid of) was a similar question to mine.

Here is the link:

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file

Basically the fix was to ensure that you don't copy any frameworks into your project folder. In my case I had copied some frameworks in there and as such I just needed to delete them. Thanks to Jordan for that info.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the answer on stackoverflow which (I was afraid of) was a similar question to mine.

Here is the link:

[Fix for app running on iphone device but not in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file)

Basically the fix was to ensure that you don't copy any frameworks into your project folder. In my case I had copied some frameworks in there and as such I just needed to delete them. Everything works fine now thanks to Jordan in the link posted above.