# '__weak' only applies to objective-c object or block pointer types; type here is int" warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, cocoapods

I'm Using AFNetworking (3.1.0) in Pods, and I'm trying to subclass SessionManager class in it.

When I try to use:

```
 __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

in the subclass, I get an error

'__weak' only applies to objective-c object or block pointer types; type here is int" warning

I see this is similar to:

['__strong' only applies to objective-c object or block pointer types; type here is XXX" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430933/strong-only-applies-to-objective-c-object-or-block-pointer-types-type-here/26682008#26682008)

I checked my framework search paths, but I did not have framework path listed there.

In the framework search path for my target settings:

```
$(inherited) non-recursive
$(PROJECT_DIR) non-recursive
$(PODS_ROOT) recursive
```

I'm not sure what to change to fix the error.

Pods_Test.Framework Header:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
#ifndef FOUNDATION_EXPORT
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern "C"
#else
#define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern
#endif
#endif
#endif


FOUNDATION_EXPORT double Pods_Test_ContactVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char Pods_Test_ContactVersionString[];
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which version of AFNetworking are you using ?

Comment: Using AFNetworking (3.1.0) @AntonMalmygin

Comment: Did you tried to explicitly use the name of you subclass instead of `typeof(self)` ?

Comment: I tried __weak typeof(BackgroundSessionManager) weakSelf = self;, and still gives me the same error

Comment: And just `__weak BackgroundSessionManager weakSelf = self;` not working too ?

Comment: yes @AntonMalmygin

Comment: what is `self` in here

Comment: self is pointing to BackgroundSessionManager which is a subclass of SessionManager in AFNetwroking. @PranjalBikashDas

Comment: Do you somehow have two types named `BackgroundSessionManager` linked in?

Comment: I created BackgroundSessionManager by adding new file to Xcode. It created .h and .m in Xcode. I only see these two files. How can there be two types of BackgroundSessionManager ?@JoshCaswell

Comment: any solution for this?