# error while loading project into device..about libsqlite3.0dylib file is missing

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am developimg an app. In the middle of my project suddenly the libsqlite3.0dylib file turned into red color. When I was trying to load the project into simulator it was running and into device it was showing the rolling error.

I removed the red color file and freshly added the libsqlite3.0dylib file. Then also it showing error. I have seen many more forums and did not get the right choice to proceed with my app.

What might cause this and how do I solve it?

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
>   ld: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file for architecture i386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Target`'s `Build Settings`, remove everything in `Framework Search Paths`. This should fix your issue.

Hope this helps !

**P.S**: This is an issue that has been on SO before. You can see solutions here, [Build Error - missing required architecture i386 in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file/1467238#1467238) .

Since you fail to understand `how` to solve the issue, I will also attach a photo on how your `Framework Search Paths` should look. `Empty`.

[image]

Comment: @SAHARA I just told you **HOW** and also gave you a link as reference to **READ** yourself and solve your issue.