# Facebook-iOS-SDK: How to correct build framework and add it to project?

Tags: facebook, linker, facebook-ios-sdk

I develop an app for iPad.

At now, i test application on **iPad-5.1 Simulator**.

And for my unhappiness, application falls down.

1) I use **FacebookSDK 3.0**
2) Compile **FacebookSDK** into Framework **FBiOSSDK**
3) Add Framework **FBiOSSDK** to project
4) See log of **Linker**
5) Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_open_v2" and many-many "_sqlite3_*" symbols.

Maybe i set wrong options to facebook-sdk project when build it to framework?

Can anybody help?

After search, i find a solution:

"Add to project libsqlite3.0.dylib"

But **Linker** said: 
  "ignoring file /path/libsqlite3.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file"

-- Main Problem --

After an hour, i've found out, that i link framework in wrong way.

Script create it in local directory (not in **System/Library/Frameworks** or **Library/Frameworks**).

After adding it, `Framework Search Paths` changes to not default value.

How to build framework in right way?

Thanks!

Comment: try cleaning Framework Search Paths in project build settings, here is the question about libsqlite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file

Comment: and make sure you've compiled FBiOSSDK for i386 (see build settings -> architectures)

Comment: thanks, i understand my fault. but how to compile project into *.framework to add it from default /framework directory? i build it with shell scripts, that are coming with facebook-sdk

Comment: as I understand, you should only add this framework into you project's frameworks (on Summary tab of you project settings). You can also read this: http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/ There are some tricks about setting up project settings in the middle of it

Comment: yes, i need to add framework, but first, i need to build it in default directory like */System/Library/Frameworks* or */Library/Frameworks*. But scripts, that i use (author of framework append it to facebook-sdk), build framework in *local directory*, not in *default framework directory*

Comment: you could set Build Location to whatever you need, but why do you need this? you can add framework from every directory, as I know

Comment: yes, but as many guys say: *you need to set to default **Framework Search Paths***. after adding framework, it will rewrite it's path to **Framework Search Paths**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, after a long time i make such things to make this **FacebookSDK** work:

1)First, I delete build of **FacebookSDK framework** (**rm -rf**) and run script for building framework (**build_framework.sh**)

2)After that, i add to project (*project* -> *build phases* -> *link binary with libraries* ) **FacebookSDK.framework** (from ***local*** directory, with button ***add other***) and **libsqlite3.0dylib** and **libsqlite3.dylib** (just search it in search-field!)

0) or 3)And After that i make this: find directory *~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData* and delete ***EVERYTHING*** from this. (use command **rm -rf dir_name/***)

You can do it from step 3) that i also named step 0).

Here i provide a script, which can help you

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $pathToCacheDirectory = qq(~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/);

sub TaskToDo{
    my ($refToArgv)=@_;
    die "can't work with too much parameters" unless(scalar(@$refToArgv)==1);
    my $what = shift @$refToArgv;
    my $time = 30; #wait 30 seconds in each iteration
    my $workRef = sub{
        print "i will delete: ";
        print qx(ls $pathToCacheDirectory);
    qx(rm -rf $pathToCacheDirectory);
    };
    #view help
    if ($what eq 'help'){
        print qx(perldoc -t $0);
    }
    #list directory 
    if ($what eq 'watch'){
    print qx(ls $pathToCacheDirectory);
    }
    #kill files instantly
    if ($what eq 'now'){
    print 'kill now'.qq(\n);
    $workRef->();
    print 'see result'.qq(\n);
    print qx(ls $pathToCacheDirectory);
    }
    #switch on watcher
    if ($what eq 'work'){
    for(;;){
        #in INF loop
        for my $s(0..4){
        #print "this is <<$_>>\n";
        print "time remaining: ".(5-$s)*$time." sec \n";
        sleep($time);
        }
        $workRef->();    
        sleep(10);
    }
    }
} 

TaskToDo(\@ARGV);



__END__

=head1 DESCRIPTION

This script clear directory with cache from Xcode

    -- 'help'  will show this log

    -- 'work'  will run script as observer and killer

    -- 'watch' will show info about directory with cache

    -- 'now'   will kill all instantly

    Example: perl scriptName.pl help

=cut
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to go to the Target Info and delete the Framework search path that XCode created. Then everything compiled correctly.