# ignoring file [path] missing required architecture i386 in file

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4.5

I'm quite new to Xcode and Iphone development and ran into the following problem:

I opened a new project and added *.h and a *.a files (which I recived from a certain device vendor). 
I get the following warning:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/udi/Desktop/Xcode/Xcode Projects/Scosche/libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/udi/Desktop/Xcode/Xcode Projects/Scosche/libmyTrekSDK_armv7.a (2 slices)

If I ignore the warning, and try to instanciate the class that is given to me in the header file, I get these errors:

> ld: warning: ignoring file [Path/FileName.a], missing required architecture i386 in file [Path/FileName.a] (2 slices)
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HRMonitor", referenced from:
>
> objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I've checked the Framework Search Pathes (as mantioned in many other posts) and it clear.

More info:

1. I'm Using Xcode 4.6.1
2. The files are currently located at project's root folder.
3. I'm using a Single View Application tamplate.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This warning means that you're trying to use library made for Device (ARM) with your Simulator (i386).

You can use this terminal command to create a universal library:

```
lipo -create lib_arm.a lib_i386.a -output lib_universal.a
```

More info about **lipo** command [here](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/lipo/).

Comment: I guess the libraries need to exist for both armv7 and i386, right ?

Comment: Got "can't open input file: lib_arm.a (No such file or directory)"

Is there a specific spot where you're supposed to run this command?

Comment: @shim, you should change directory to the one, where your static libs (arm and i386) are, like this:
$ cd /libs/
$ lipo -create *name_of_your_arm_lib*.a *name_of_your_386_lib*.a -output lib_universal.a

Comment: @ Dmitry Zhukov can you show me how can I know the directory of my static libs , because i met the same error like Shim

Comment: @tommy **lipo** makes universal lib from libs with specific arch_types (or vice versa) and *lib_arm.a* here is just a placeholder. You can use *your_lib_name.a* if specific libs are located in same folder, or you can just use *path_to_your_lib/your_lib.a*. Hope this helps.

Comment: My bad .. I was trying to run on simulator instead of device. Didn't change anything and just run my application over my iPad and everything is good.

Comment: I have a BluetoothManager.framework in my app, with the two .h files included. App runs well on iPad but I get the i386 error when I try it on the simulator. Can't finsd a way around.

Comment: @Jorgen did you find any solution for same.? I have case where I have .framework and facing same issue.

Answer (score 8):

Change your target's "Build Settings > Build Active Architectures Only" to "No"

This is doing the same thing as Dmitry Zhukov's answer but doing it thru Xcode instead of going around its back.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with a 3rd party code, keep in mind that some SDKs may not work on the simulator. The same build error I have encountered vanished, when I ran the project on the device.