# universal IOS static library with i386 x86_64 armv7 armv7s arm64

Tags: ios, xcode6, static-libraries, cross-compiling

I need to create an universal library of a Cocoa Touch Static library project,

I am using

```
xcodebuild -target mysdsk ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO VALID_ARCHS="arm64 armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"
```

Even if I split the iphonesimulator as two xcodebuild still I could not get i386 for iphone4 simuator

I am getting error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386
```

Based on [How do I determine the target architecture of static library (.a) on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085137/how-do-i-determine-the-target-architecture-of-static-library-a-on-mac-os-x)

I tried to run the file command, it displays

```
mysdsk.a: Mach-O universal binary with 5 architectures
mysdsk.a (for architecture i386): current ar archive random library
mysdsk.a (for architecture armv7): current ar archive random library
mysdsk.a (for architecture armv7s): current ar archive random library
mysdsk.a (for architecture x86_64): current ar archive random library
mysdsk.a (for architecture arm64): current ar archive random library
```

But still I am getting error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever method you have followed, From the list of architectures I think everything is fine.

There is one issue with XCode that even if you drag an drop the **mysdsk.a** or change inside the linker setttings, The XCode can still pick a wrong file which is stored inside

```
/Users/<your username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mysdsk_........ folder
```

You can identify from XCode warnings saying 3 slices but it is actually 5 slices

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mysdsk_......./..../mysdsk.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mysdsk_......./..../mysdsk.a (3 slices)

Therefore Delete the folder /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mysdsk_........

Then it should be working fine, Actually I identified this issue that the other machine works fine but my machine was not working.

Reference [ignoring file [path] missing required architecture i386 in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659631/ignoring-file-path-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file)

Comment: Found usefull but, it seems little bit work around, I will try

Comment: Actually I was bit sceptical about this workaround, but the solution solved my problem, I am accepting this as an answer, If possible please provide proper Bug/Issue location if this is already addressed in apple developer forum