# Undefined symbols for architecture i386:"_OBJC_CLASS_$_HyperLocalAd", referenced from:

Tags: iphone

I am adding a static library to my project and it is added successfully.Set Library paths for its folder in build settings.I have also removed valid architectures from build settings.Still after compiling it gives me error required architecture missing.What can I do for that.

[image]

[image]
[image]

ALSO tried force load on other linking flags

[image]

Comment: Check this link & try to follow all instructions in discussions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file

Comment: since yesterday noon, I have tried all the links including this one.Other libraries are working except one

Comment: Delete & add this library again & then clean your Xcode restart your device & check....

Comment: The linker is telling you that `libuniversalHyperLocalAd.a` is missing the `i386` architecture.  To check this go to the command line and run `file` on the `.a` file.

Comment: yes I have checked its architecture:-- armv6 , armv7

Answer (score 0):

You don't have all the frameworks required for adwhirl for one. Try adding all of the ones in their SDK "required frameworks" section then try.

[Adwhirl frameworks](https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/ios/AdWhirliOSSDKSetup.html)