# AWS iOS SDK -> Missing Required Architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use the amazon AWS for iOS SDK but I keep getting several Apple Mach-O Linker errors in Xcode 6.1.1, this error happened when i'm trying to use iOS simulator iPhone 5s but it works fine on  4s simulator. Any help would be much appreciate.

AWS Framework I'm using is AWSiOSSDK v 1.7.0

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/xxx/Downloads/xxxios_app/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK,
>   missing required architecture x86_64 in file
>   /Users/xxx/Downloads/xxx_ios_app/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK (3
>   slices) ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/xxx/Downloads/xxx_ios_app/AWSiOSSDK.framework/AWSiOSSDK,
>   missing required architecture x86_64 in file
>   /Users/xxx/Downloads/xxx_ios_app/AWSiOSSDK.framework/AWSiOSSDK (3
>   slices) Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS$AmazonEndpoints", referenced from: objc-class-ref in
>   LoginViewController.o objc-class-ref in PhotoViewController.o
>   "_OBJC_CLASS$AmazonErrorHandler", referenced from: objc-class-ref in
>   LoginViewController.o objc-class-ref in PhotoViewController.o
>   "_OBJC_CLASS$AmazonLogger", referenced from: objc-class-ref in
>   LoginViewController.o objc-class-ref in PhotoViewController.o
>   "_OBJC_CLASS$AmazonS3Client", referenced from: objc-class-ref in
>   LoginViewController.o objc-class-ref in PhotoViewController.o
>   "_OBJC_CLASS$FBNativeDialogs", referenced from: objc-class-ref in
>   LoginViewController.o "_OBJC_CLASS$_FBRequestConnection", referenced
>   from: objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o objc-class-ref in
>   PhotoViewController.o

Comment: other issue I see on your project is that to fix x86_64 issue architechture. Go to Targes > Build Settings  and search for architecture and select standard architecture. and on Valid architecture add armv7 and arm64

Comment: The version 1 of the AWS Mobile SDK is deprecated. You should consider upgrading to the [version 2](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/).

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949338/2245240

This happens when you add a framework to your project and unintentionally copy the framework into your project directory.

The fix is to check your project directory (where you store your project on disk) for any iphone SDK *.Framework files and delete them.

Project will build fine afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! This is the only thing that worked for me!