# Jabber Framework error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cisco

I am trying to implement JabberGuest.framework in my application, but its shows an error.
[image]

Please help me.

Comment: None of these answers worked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file

Comment: Add proper path in your Header seach path in build setting.

Answer (score 0):

it needs DDLog (aka CocoaLumberjack) => you are missing a precondition.
You need to download & link it in (embedd it in the app)