# IMFPush Bluemix not working on Swift 2.2 (i386 error)

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

Anyone knows how to solve this error? I can't compile my project with IMFPush library =/

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/kersul/Develop/Grabit_iOS/Pods/IMFPush/Frameworks/IMFPush.framework/IMFPush,
>   missing required architecture i386 in file
>   /Users/kersul/Develop/Grabit_iOS/Pods/IMFPush/Frameworks/IMFPush.framework/IMFPush
>   (2 slices) Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IMFPushClient", referenced from:
>             type metadata accessor for __ObjC.IMFPushClient in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: Can you provide recreation steps for this issue. How did you import the obj-c libraries into your project. Are you using a bridging header to convert the obj-c to swift. Does this only happen when you attempt to build for the simulator. What about a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions around that seem to tackle this issue.

I would first take a look at [Jordan's advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file)
and ensure that the framework was added to your project correctly. Additionally ensure that the framework [has been linked correctly](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html)

If neither fixes the issue then also see the [answer posed by Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984368/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objc-class-skpsmtpmessage-referenc) and check to see if your .m file is listed under your compile sources.

That said, i386 architecture is what is used by the iOS Simulator. Do be aware that the Simulator cannot replicate push functionality, so even if you are able to compile IMFPush for it, it will not function correctly.